# How to know if TTS is done

Tags: c#, xamarin, text-to-speech

I want to made a simple assistant, but I need to know if the tts is done.

I'm using the code of Xamarin page: https://github.com/xamarin/monodroid-samples/blob/master/PlatformFeatures/TextToSpeech/TextToSpeech/MainActivity.cs

Thanks to much

Comment: Why don't you try to launch the sample you have linked?

Comment: For general cross-platform solution you may look into a cloud service like Microsoft Azure Cognitive Services, or you will have to implement the TTS for each operating system separately, because there is no shared API for this.

Comment: You can set `setOnUtteranceProgressListener` https://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech#setOnUtteranceProgressListener(android.speech.tts.UtteranceProgressListener)